# JQuery - Show multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble making a working show div and I just can't get it.
So I have the following:

```js
function GetCaptcha() {
$(".panel-captcha").fadeIn(500);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="GetCaptcha()"> Get </a>
<div class="panel-captcha">
TEXT
</div>
```

The div has the display:none tag.
It works very well, but I have one problem. I need to have many divs inside the same page ( not the same, it may change from database ). If I have 3 or 4 panels, when I click the button it will show them all instead only the div where I have the link to show.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Complete HTML file...

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-blue" data-widget='{"draggable": "false"}'>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2>TEXT</h2>
      <div class="panel-ctrls">
        <a href="#" class="button-icon" onClick="GetCaptcha(this)"><i class="ti ti-eye"></i></a> 
        <!-- BUTTON TO SHOW CAPTCHA -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <small>Other Text...</small>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="tabular">
        <div class="tabular-row tabular-row">
          <div class="tabular-cell">
            <span class="status-total"><strong>More Text...</strong></span>
          </div>
          <div class="tabular-cell">
            <span class="status-pending">Other Text...</span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-captcha">
      <!-- HIDDEN DIV -->
      <div class="tabular-cell">
        HIDDEN TEXT
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END HIDDEN DIV -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use, next, sibling, or closest to find the closest div with class hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the reference of element to click handler, then use `.next()`

*Script*

```js
function GetCaptcha(elem) {
  $(elem).next(".panel-captcha").fadeIn(500);
}
```

```css
.panel-captcha {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onClick="GetCaptcha(this)"> Get </a>
<div class="panel-captcha">
  TEXT
</div>
```

As you are using jQuery bind event using it.

*HTML*

```
<a href="#" class="captcha"> Get </a>
<div class="panel-captcha">
  TEXT
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(function() {
  $('.captcha').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next(".panel-captcha").fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

As per updated HTML use

```
function GetCaptcha(elem) {
  $(elem).closest('.panel').find(".panel-captcha").fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work. It's weird because it works good in fiddle but when using it in my code, isn't working... =\

Comment: I figured why it isn't working. It's because I want the button inside another DIV and that div isn't right below. Any clue in how to solve it?

Comment: @Tiago can you share the exact html

Comment: I've added the full code in the main question. If I have the button in the second div tabular cell ( Where's "Other Text..." ), this code works: $(elem).parents().next(".panel-captcha").slideToggle(500); . But the button where it is doesn't works.

Comment: @Tiago, Use `$(elem).closest('.panel').find(".panel-captcha").fadeIn(500);`